# Archiving deleted records in multiple tables using triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am using MySQL 5.0.95.  I have a web form where customers can create a guest list for their event, the guest list will be approved by the office manager, and from that the front desk gets the day's approved visitors.

I have boiled the problem down to save space.  I have two tables, _events and _guests. I also have two matching archive tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS visitor._events (
eventId int( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
eventName varchar( 200 ) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ( eventId ) 
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  visitor._archived_events (
eventId int( 11 ) NOT NULL,
eventName varchar( 200 ) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ( eventId ) 
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  visitor._guests (
guestId int( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
eventId int( 11 ) NOT NULL,
guestName varchar( 200 ) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ( guestId ) 
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  visitor._archived_guests (
guestId int( 11 ) NOT NULL,
eventId int( 11 ) NOT NULL,
guestName varchar( 200 ) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ( guestId ) 
);
```

I want the office manager to be able to delete events (and their guest records) from the database once the event is over, but I'd like those events to be archived for the year for records management.

I've created a TRIGGER that will copy any record DELETED from the _guests table into the _archive_guests table.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS TR_A_DEL_guests $$

CREATE TRIGGER TR_A_DEL_guests DELETE ON _guests FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

 INSERT IGNORE INTO _archived_guests (
   guestId,
   guestName
 ) VALUES (
   OLD.guestId,
   guestName
 );

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

I also have a TRIGGER that will DELETE all guest records for the specific eventID from the _guests table and then copy any DELETED record from the _events table into the _archived_events table.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS TR_A_DEL_events $$

CREATE TRIGGER TR_A_DEL_events AFTER DELETE ON _events FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

 DELETE FROM _guests WHERE eventId = OLD.eventId;

 INSERT IGNORE INTO _archived_events (
   eventId,
   eventName
 ) VALUES (
   OLD.idEventId,
   OLD.eventName
 );

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

The upshot is that when a record is deleted from _events, it is moved to _archived_events and all the _guests records for that event are copied to the _archived_guests table.

The problem I have is that now, when the customer is editing their guest list, if they delete a guest record, it is archived.  They are able to edit/delete guests but not delete the event altogether.

My question:
Is there any way to use only one TRIGGER on deleted events that will first copy *each* of the appropriate _guest records (eventId = OLD.eventId) to _archived_guests and then copy the _event record to _archived_events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly try

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS TR_A_DEL_events_guests $$
CREATE TRIGGER TR_A_DEL_events_guests 
BEFORE DELETE ON _events 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    -- Archive guests
    INSERT IGNORE INTO _archived_guests (guestId, eventId, guestName)
    SELECT guestId, eventId, guestName
      FROM _guests
     WHERE eventId = OLD.eventId;
    -- Delete guests 
    DELETE 
      FROM _guests 
     WHERE eventId = OLD.eventId;
    -- Archive event before deleting
    INSERT IGNORE INTO _archived_events (eventId, eventName)
    VALUES (OLD.eventId, OLD.eventName);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/880b8/1)** demo

Comment: Excellent!  I had gotten into a cycle of trying all sorts of complex solutions trying to use loops and cursors and such.  Thank you.